# Can someone check this code to check the leap year?

Tags: javascript

The code is below, i cant seem to get it to work, is there any issue? Do i have to change something? Preferably, Id like to stick to my format rather than return true or false. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Basic Task 2</title>
<style>
h1 {font-family:serif; font-size:48px; color:#ff00ff; text-align:center}
h2 {font-family:sans-serif; font-size:36px; color:#0000ff; text-align:center}
h3 {font-family:sans-serif; font-size:30px; color:#f0000f; text-align: left}
</style>
</head>
<body>

 <div align="center">

<h1 id="type1">Checking whether a year is leap or not</h1>
<h3 id="type3"></h3>

</div>
<form id="numtype" action="/action_page.php" style="font-size: 24px">

    <input id="year" type="number" name="num" style="font-size: 24px" placeholder="Enter year">  <br><br>

    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit" style="font-size: 24px">

<script>

    function myFunction()   {
        
        var yar = document.getElementById('year').value

            if      (yar % 100 == 0)
                document.getElementById('type2').innerHTML= (num+" is NOT a leap year.")
            elif    (yar % 400 == 0 & yar % 4 == 0)
                document.getElementById('type2').innerHTML= (num +" is a leap year.")
            else
                document.getElementById('type2')("unknown input")
                            }
</script>
<h2 id="type2"></h2>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: _"is there any issue?"_ - Obviously, otherwise it would work. Please describe why you think it does not work? Any errors? False result? What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? Add test cases and the expected output.

Comment: hi, i apologise for the above, I'm a student and very new to this. The only time ive gotten results, every single year displays as "not a leap year", i cant get it to display the correct results.

Comment: `elif ` should be throwing an error in your browser dev tools console (F12). Always start there when debugging. Many of the messages you run into you may not quite understand , although they are quite informative themselses, but you can do a web search with them and most of the time find valuable results

Comment: `&` is the bitwise AND not the logical AND `&&`

Comment: you are missing `</form>` somewhere

Comment: this is the error I'm getting `Leap Year Check.html:23 Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunctions is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick (Leap Year Check.html:23)` I do not know what it means.

Comment: What is this: `document.getElementById('type2')("unknown input")`?

Comment: Looks like a spelling issue. Code shown has `myFunction` but error has `myFunctions` with an `s`. Do a web search for *javascript function undefined* or similar terms just to see how many results show up

Comment: Your function is undefined because as mentioned by @charlietfl that `elif` is breaking your function.

Comment: Looks like OP typed out that error by hand, not copy paste, and thus introduced the false-flag on a spelling issue

Comment: `document.getElementById('year').value` returns a string...
Surround it whith `Number(` and `)`.

Comment: what is `num`?!?

Answer (score 0):

Don't blame me...

```js
const myForm = document.getElementById('my-form')
  ,   eType2 = document.getElementById('type2')
  ,  isLeapYear = y => ((y % 4 == 0) && (y % 100 != 0)) || (y % 400 == 0)
  ;
myForm.onsubmit = e => 
  {
  e.preventDefault() // prevent form submission an page reload
  let yar = myForm.year.valueAsNumber  // get the year value as number ( and not as string )
  eType2.textContent = isLeapYear(yar) ? `${yar} is a leap year.` : `${yar} is NOT a leap year.`
  }
```

```css
h1 {font-family:serif; font-size:48px; color:#ff00ff; text-align:center}
h2 {font-family:sans-serif; font-size:36px; color:#0000ff; text-align:center}
form, button, input { font-size:24px; }

div.centerAll {margin: 1em auto; text-align: center; }
```

```html
<div class="centerAll">

  <h1>Checking whether a year is leap or not</h1>

  <form id="my-form" action="">
  
    <input type="number" name="year" placeholder="Enter year"  min="0" value="0" required>
    <br><br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  
  <h2 id="type2"></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: indentation, commas not at end of lines, to me - it's a mess and hard on the eyes.  I didn't check if it works...

Comment: hi, this works perfectly. Thank you very much for your time. Unfortunately, i dont understand a single part of the initial snippet as a novice.

Comment: @iAmOren everyone forgot to add the comma at the end of the line, especially when there are long code pages, that's why I put them like this. And that respects the syntactic rules of javascript

Comment: @MisterJojo - I know your comma scheme works, "everyone forgot" -> "everyone forgets" -> not true - I (almost) never forget.  Personally, I'd split the 'const' to separate lines for clarity.  I wouldn't use `const` nor `let` anywhere - I'm personally against that, becuase I think it is counter-javascript = "to `var` or not to `var`?" is the only question for me... :)

Answer (score 0):

A year is a leap year if it is a multiple of 4, but not if it's also a multiple of 100, unless it's also a multiple of 400.
every 400 years there are 97 leap years: 400/4 - 400/100 + 400/400 = 100 + 4 - 1 = 97.

```
function isLeap(year) {
  return ( (year%4!=0)?false:
           (year%400==0)?true:
           (year%100==0)?false:
           true
         );
}
```

So, change:

```
    function myFunction()   {
        
        var yar = document.getElementById('year').value

            if      (yar % 100 == 0)
                document.getElementById('type2').innerHTML= (num+" is NOT a leap year.")
            elif    (yar % 400 == 0 & yar % 4 == 0)
                document.getElementById('type2').innerHTML= (num +" is a leap year.")
            else
                document.getElementById('type2')("unknown input")
                            }
```

to:

```
  function myFunction() {
    var yar=Number(document.getElementById('year').value);
    document.getElementById('type2').innerText=yar+" is "+(isLeap(yar)?"":"NOT ")+"a leap year.");
  }
```

Comment: what am i exactly supposed to switch here? if i only switch the contents of the Function  then nothing happens?

Comment: I don't understand.  did you add the isLeap function?

Comment: So?  Where are we?